# Installed plugin not listed in Plug-in selection

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently developing an eclipse plugin and I struggle when it comes to list my plugin dependencies.

I installed the OCL plugin on my eclipse installation and when I want to add it to the project dependencies via the GUI I cannot find it in the plug-in selection list proposed by eclipse.

Even when I reference it manually in the MANIFEST.MF it gives me a warning "`org.eclipse.ocl plugin cannot be resolved`". However, when I run my plugin as an eclipse application, all is working fine.

I don't know why I get those false signal issues and how to benefit from the Plug-in selection GUI in order to set up the dependencies of my project. Hope that someone have an anwser for that.

Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such issues I strongly advise you to use a clearly defined [target platform](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html) instead of relying on the plug-ins installed in your Eclipse IDE instance. Basically, a target platform is an XML file that specifies all the plug-ins that should be in your dev environment.

The pros of using a target platform are that:

- you don't have to struggle to re-install all the plug-ins in the correct version when you move from an Eclipse IDE instance to another,
- it is easier to work in a team,
- you know exactly the plug-ins that are in your dev environment, making it easier to determine why a dependency is not found
- the target platform can be used to automate the build with Maven and [Tycho](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/).

When no target platorm is specified, Eclipse IDE will use the plug-ins available in your Eclipse installation so I find strange that the `org.eclipse.ocl` bundle cannot be resolved. But let's try to fix that.

### 1. Check your current target platform

You can use the *Target Platform State* view to see all the bundles currently provided by the target platform in use:

[image: The Target Platform State view shows bundles available in the dev environment]

> To open it: `Window > Show View > Other... > Plug-in Development`

All the plug-ins that you see here can be used as dependencies of your own plug-ins.

If the `org.eclipse.ocl` bundle is not listed here you should check the details of the target platform in use from the *Preferences* dialog:

[image: Details about the target platform can be seen in the Preferences]

> To open it: `Window > Preferences > Plug-in Development > Target Platform`

If you:

1. select the target platform,
2. click on `Edit...`,
3. go to the `Content` tab,

you should see the list of all the plug-ins currently installed in Eclipse. Make sure that `org.eclipse.ocl` is listed **and checked**.

### 2. If the plug-in is not listed in the target platform

Should not happen if at runtime the plug-in behaves as expected, but in this case OCL has not been properly installed.

### 3. If the plug-in is listed in the target platform and checked

In this case it is likely that Eclipse is a bit confused. You should be able to fix the issue by:

1. either rebuilding the workspace (`Project > Clean... > Clean`)
2. or reloading the target platform (`Window > Preferences > Plug-in Development > Target Platform > Select Running Platform > Reload`).

> In rare occasions I also had to clear all metadata by launching Eclipse IDE in the command line with the [`-clean -clearPersistedState` options](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html).

I know that it may not actually answer your question but since I cannot comment yet I hope it will at least provide you some tips for the future!