# Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.lucene

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am pretty new to Eclipse.
I try to set up the Eclipse plugin development environment for this:
https://github.com/ajermakovics/eclipse-instasearch

I followed the instruction
Build using Maven from project root:

```
(in "eclipse-instasearch" folder)
mvn install

Use File -> Import -> Existing Projects to import all instasearch projects ("eclipse-instasearch" folder)
To run or debug right click on 'instasearch' project and select Run As -> Eclipse Application
```

in "MANIFEST.MF" it complains "Bundle 'org.apache.lucene' cannot be resolved"

Run As Eclipse Application will show this exception in the Console :

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: it.unibz.instasearch [19]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.lucene; bundle-version="[2.9.1,2.9.2]"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1844)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1837)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1778)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1742)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1664)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileSnapshot).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

the plugin does not load, unable to see in the menu.

I also tried "Open Project From FileSystem" to open the root folder, in this way there is no option "Run As Eclipse Application" in the context menu.

I must missed something,
any one can guide me?

Comment: It wants the org.apache.lucene plug-in which hasn't been included in Eclipse for a long time. If you read through the other issues on the github site there appear to be some workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

By default Eclipse uses its own environment (i.e. the installed plug-ins) to resolve the dependencies of the plug-in projects. As @greg-449 said in comments Lucene is not included by default anymore and that's why the build fails. You basically have two choices to solve the issue:

1. Add the Lucene plug-in to the environment (it can be found in Orbit's update sites: https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/)
2. Wrap Lucene's JAR files in an Eclipse plug-in: [How to create Eclipse plug-ins from Java libraries (JAR files)](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJarToPlugin/article.html) and add the resulting plug-in to the repository.

The tradeoffs are that wrapping JAR files in an Eclipse plug-in is a bit more work (to create & maintain) whereas adding Lucene to the environment through Orbit will slow down the build. Moreover, "adding Lucene to the environment" currently means "installing the plug-in in Eclipse", which is only a per-developer solution. If you're envisioning maintaining the plug-in I would suggest you to consider using a [target platform](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html) instead: that would make the environment platform-independant (I wrote a bit about that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58294479/10226142)).

Finally, it seems that a fork of *eclipse-instasearch* already addresses this issue. You'll find it easily by browsing latest GitHub issues.